# How to create a new field using IterationPath as data source

Tags: tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem, tfs-process-template

We want to extend the bug work item template with a new field called **Found In Iteration**. This field, what a surprise, should contains the iteration the bug was found in. But when I created the new field of type `TreePath`, I got an error when importing the process template into the Team Project Collection (TPC) stating that `TreePath` is only a valid field type for `IterationPath` and `AreaPath` fields.

Looking at that I'm wondering if there is at least any way to add a field to a work item template that uses the iteration path as data source and stores the selected value in another field (e.g. `FoundInIteration`).

Comment: I was trying to achieve exactly the same thing today following feedback from our test team.  What approach have you gone with in the end?  It looks like I'm going to have to go with hardcoded release labels which is pretty nasty.

Comment: We are still pondering. But I prefer using a standard text field with a match element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404842.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. There can neither be custom fields of type `TreePath` nor fields refering to `System.IterationPath`.